# How to get CMake to build, but not run, a test

Tags: cmake

In CMake, how do I indicate that a C test program should be built, but not run?

For the netCDF C library, a free software science data package used by weather, climate, and space scientists, we have both a CMake and an autotools build. The code is available on [github](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c). You can see the CMake files there.

In our tests we have some shell scripts and some C programs. In this case, I need some shell script actions to complete before the C test is run. Since I want all this to work with parallel builds, the easiest solution seems to be to have the shell program call the C test program when it needs to, and not call the C test program during testing at all.

For example I have a test program tst_interops3.c (in directory nc_test4). I also have a shell script test run_get_hdf4_files.sh. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This shell gets files from the netCDF ftp site for testing.

# $Id: run_get_hdf4_files.sh,v 1.4 2009/07/15 15:16:05 ed Exp $

set -e
echo ""
file_list="AMSR_E_L2_Rain_V10_200905312326_A.hdf AMSR_E_L3_DailyLand_V06_20020619.hdf \
    MYD29.A2009152.0000.005.2009153124331.hdf MYD29.A2002185.0000.005.2007160150627.hdf \
    MOD29.A2000055.0005.005.2006267200024.hdf"
echo "Getting HDF4 test files $file_list"

for f1 in $file_list
do
    if ! test -f $f1; then
    curl -O "ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf/sample_data/hdf4/$f1.gz"
    gunzip $f1.gz
    fi
done

${execdir}/tst_interops3

echo "SUCCESS!!!"

exit 0
```

This script downloads some data files, and then runs program tst_interops3, which reads the data files to ensure that netCDF can read HDF4 data files. (HDF4 is a legacy science data format).

In autotools, I list tst_interops3 in check_PROGRAMS, but not TESTS. This causes it to be built, but not run. (It is run in the script.)

However, I can't figure out how to do the same thing in CMake. How do I get a test program to build, but not run?

Comment: Please show what you have with cmake already, and then we will be able to better point out a fix

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined "check" target in CMake; most of test infrastructures used with CMake defines "test" pseudo-target, but not a "check".

So you may define "check" target manually, and set it dependent from every target (like executable) you want to build at this stage:

```
# Add "check" target which simply executes "ctest" for perform testing.
add_custom_target(check COMMAND "ctest")

# Create an executable which is needed only for testing.
# It *won't* be built on "make all" or "make".
add_executable(test_program_a EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test_program_a.c)

# Mark the executable to be built on "make check".
add_dependencies(check test_program_a)

# Create some test which involves the executable created above.
# This test is executed on "ctest" (or "make test").
# So it will be executed on "make check" too, after building the test program.
add_test(NAME test.01 COMMAND test_program_a "val1")
```

Comment: I don't actually want to define a "check" target. There already is a "test" target. I want my program to build when the user does "make test", but not run. The program is to be run by a script. - But thanks for your answer, I think it contains what I need to get this working.

Comment: You cannot attach (that is, add dependency) to the "test" target anything except tests, because it is a "pseudo" target.